# Should i use git add before or git commit before

Tags: linux, git, version-control, centos

I have read the docs as well but could not get one thing.

Suppose I added new files to the repo.

Then which command do I need to execute first:

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git commit - m "test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first execute `git add .` to stage the new/modified files and then `git commit -m "your message"` to write those changes to the repository.

You can see in [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) the different file statuses in git, and I strongly recommend you to read the whole book.

EDIT:

To make it clear, what you are doing with `git add .` is basically telling git 'Hey, I have new/modified/untracked files that I'd like to include in my next commit', so that the next time you execute `git commit` those files changes are written to the repository.

Comment: Yep @user33, look at HieryNomus' answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add before you commit. Otherwise there is nothing new to commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in one go if all the changes files belong to a single commit:

```
git commit -a -m "<your message>"
```

Comment: is there any diff between `-a` and `-A`

Comment: `git commit --help` doesn't show a `-A` option, where are you getting that from?